# Numpy expand dataset column and index wise and interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I want to transform and expand a numpy array
The columns should be in increments of 1 and rows in increments of 1/10
The values in the dataset should be interpolated linearly
I have attached an image of what I need

My code is clunky and ugly, there must be a more elegant and simple solution.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
    # Generate a sample data set with random ints 
    # Columns are degrees in steps of 30 and index is tp in steps of 1
    
    # Goal is to expand the dataset column wise in steps of 1 degree and interpolate inbetween
    # And expand index wise in steps of 0.1 between the ints and interpolate inbetween
    
        import numpy as np
        
        dataset=np.random.randint(1,10,(10,12))
        index=[i for i in range(10)]
        cols=[i for i in range(0,360,30)]
    
    # Generate additional 10 rows for each decimal index (tp)
    # And interpolate linearly for each 
    
        data=dataset[0,:]
        
        rows=dataset.shape[0]
        
        for tp in range(1,rows):
            row0=dataset[tp-1,:]
            row1=dataset[tp,:]
            
            delta=row1-row0
            
            for i in range(1,11):
                add=i/10*delta+row0
                data=np.vstack((data,add))
            
    # Generate columns for each degree assuming 0-360 in 30 degreee steps
    # Interpolate and also include the last from 330 back to 360 or (0)
    
        dataset=data
        
        data=dataset[:,0]
        
        for part in range(1,12):
        
            col0=dataset[:,part-1]
            col1=dataset[:,part]
        
            delta=col1-col0
        
            for i in range(1,31):    
                add=i/30*delta+col0    
                data=np.column_stack((data,add))    
                
        col11=dataset[:,11]        
        col0=dataset[:,0]
        
        delta=col0-col11    
                
        for i in range(1,30):    
            add=i/30*delta+col11    
            data=np.column_stack((data,add))
```

[image: Transformed Data]

Comment: I assume that your code is trying to solve the problem of interpolating a function on a sphere. Well, this is not a simple question. However, there are some approaches that can be used to solve this problem. Unfortu-nately, your approach based on linear interpolation is not one of them (it doesn't work). Instead, you can use spherical harmonics, spherical splines, or triangulation-based splines.

Comment: Thanks Niklas, the interpolation is not intended for a sphere, its for wind directions (0-360) and wave periods (1-14s) and allowable wave height. So all it is is to be able to split the columns into increments of 1 and the rows into increments of 0.1 (multplied by 10 inorder to get an int that can be indexed so 1.1 will be 11)